# What is the role of capacitor C3?

Tags: oscillator, passive-networks

Here you can see the schematic of an LC oscillator. When I change the value of C3 it changes whether I have oscillations or not. For example if C3=10u there are not stable oscillations, and if C3=1000p then I have oscillations.

[image: circuit diagram]

Comment: I am no expert, but IIRC this is an earthed-base configuration. C3 shorts the base to earth for AC. The 10uF you tried was probably an electrolytic one, which is not a very cood capacitor at high frequencies.

Comment: looks a bit like a Clapp oscilator

Comment: @Jasen all circuits with a few Cs and an L look 'a bit like' others. A Clapp oscillator has a series LC, in the place where a Colpitts has an L by itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q1 runs in common base in this orthodox accepted LC oscillator. This means that the base impedence should be low. In fact it should be ground as far as the RF is concerned. The term "grounded base" has been used to describe this circuit and its variants. In fact if you ground the base directly you will be up for a split supply. The oscillator you have operated well into VHF so if C3 is really big it would have a higher impedence at VHF and hence stop the oscillations due to lack of feedback. If you used 10\$\mu \$F electro things would be even worse.

Answer (score 4):

Wouter's comment is correct : this is a Colpitts oscillator, where the transistor operates in common-base configuration. So C3 keeps the base voltage grounded at AC, though its DC value is positive to bias the transistor. An electrolytic capacitor will be largely inductive by these frequencies, so if you use one it should be in parallel with a smaller ceramic capacitor, as you found.

Because a common-base amplifier is non-inverting with high voltage gain, capacitor C2 provides positive feedback from the collector (output terminal) to the emitter (input terminal) to sustain the oscillation.

(I have to say C2 looks unusually large in relation to C1, this may lower the Q of the oscillator, making it less stable than ideal)

Answer (score 2):

Look at the possibilities of the 10uF capacitor being series resonant in the MHz area: -

[image]

The picture above indicates that it could be resonant at about 300 kHz i.e. well below where the oscillator is working. This means that the capacitor is now behaving like an inductor at the oscillation frequency and all bets are off. The above graph is probably a bit extreme as it applies to capacitors like these: -

[image]

If you put the 1000 pF capacitor in parallel with the 10 uF then this should confirm.